# Google maps: hitting google query limit on maps javascript v3 api

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I need to run couple of thousand api calls to get some distances, but i keep hitting query limits. Even after i set the script to make calls every 1 seconds i still get QUERY_LIMIT as response after first 120-170 calls. After after that they keep piling up fast. So after a while it takes couple of seconds or even couple of minutes till i get an actual response.

The script does a call to get driving distance every 1 second. If ZERO_RESULT is returned then it adds a call for walking distance at the end. If that to responds with ZERO_RESULT i just calculate a radial distance by coordinates.
If it hits a query limit it ads another call for the same values to the end.

This is my code:

```
function getDistance( lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2, relId, mode, nr, total ) {
  setTimeout( function(){
      var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
      if( mode == 'driving' ) travelmode = google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING;
      else { travelmode = google.maps.TravelMode.WALKING }
      var request = {
        origin: new google.maps.LatLng( lat1, lon1 ),
        destination: new google.maps.LatLng( lat2, lon2 ),
        travelMode: travelmode
      };
      directionsService.route(request, function(result, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
            distance = parseInt( result.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value )/1000;
            $.ajaxLoadSync( 'getDistance', SITE_ROOT+'admin/modules/settings/calculateDistance.php', 'lat1='+lat1+'&long1='+lon1+'&lat2='+lat2+'&long2='+lon2+'&relId='+relId+'&distance='+distance );
        } else if( status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.ZERO_RESULTS && mode == 'driving' ){
            var walkingCount = 0;
            var limitCount = 0;
            if( $('#limit_hit').html() != '' ) limitCount = parseInt($('#limit_hit').html());
            if( $('#walking_dist').html() != '' ) walkingCount = parseInt($('#walking_dist').html());
            var offset = walkingCount + limitCount;
            $('#walking_dist').html( walkingCount + 1 );
            setTimeout(function() { getDistance( lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2, relId, 'walking', nr, total ) }, total*1000+offset*1000 );
        } else if( status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.ZERO_RESULTS && mode == 'walking' ){
            var noResult = 0;
            if( $('#no_res').html() != '' ) noResult = parseInt($('#no_res').html());
            $('#no_res').html( noResult + 1 );
            $.ajaxLoadSync( 'getDistance', SITE_ROOT+'admin/modules/settings/calculateDistance.php', 'lat1='+lat1+'&long1='+lon1+'&lat2='+lat2+'&long2='+lon2+'&relId='+relId+'&distance=-1' );
        } else if( status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OVER_QUERY_LIMIT ){
            var walkingCount = 0;
            var limitCount = 0;
            if( $('#limit_hit').html() != '' ) limitCount = parseInt($('#limit_hit').html());
            if( $('#walking_dist').html() != '' ) walkingCount = parseInt($('#walking_dist').html());
            var offset = walkingCount + limitCount;
            $('#limit_hit').html( limitCount + 1 );
            setTimeout(function() { getDistance( lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2, relId, mode, nr, total ) }, total*1000+offset*1000 );
        }
      });
  }, nr*1000 );
}
```

I would apreciate any help or tip.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/faq#usage_limits

Comment: yes i knew about that. I should have 10 request per second, but even with 1/s i`m having problems

Comment: then you are probably passing the daily limits.

Comment: That cant be. I am getting QUERY_LIMIT response after first 130-170 request ( just as i wrote above ). Also i i pass daily limit i wouldn`t be able to get any results for next 24h

Answer (score 2):

> I need to run couple of thousand api calls to get some distances

Well there's your problem.

> Use of the Google Directions API is subject to a query limit of 2,500 directions requests per day

If you need more than that, you may want to look into [Google Maps API for Business](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/). Which offers significantly more requests per day.

You could also be hitting one of these [usage limits.](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/articles/usage_limits). There are a few suggestions there on how to resolve it.

Comment: Actually you got 25,000 request for v3 api. But as i mentiond before, I`m not hitting daily limits. QUERY_LIMITS start occuring after the first 150 or so request.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for lots of driving distance results, investigate the [DistanceMatrix](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/distancematrix)

However, none of the services are intended for thousands of requests.  You may need to rethink your design (or investigate a Business License).